# How to detect special Unicode characters as equal to their base character?

Tags: javascript, typescript, internationalization

I want to implement a search field that will also find strings like "Čovjek" when entering "covjek". Of course I could hard-code every pair of a special character and its base character, but I guess there is a better way. Does anybody know how to achieve such kind of string comparison with Typescript/Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method to sanitize your string:

```
str = str.normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "").toLowerCase();
```

The normalize part separate the characters and their accents. Then the replace remove the accents. And finally we transform the string to lowercase characters.

[Normalize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize)

[Replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

[toLowerCase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase)

Comment: Thanks a lot, works great. I have not been aware of the normalize function.

Comment: glad I could help !

Answer (score 1):

**Better solution (TLDR):**

```
Intl.Collator(locale, {sensitivity:"base"}).compare(str1, str2)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Collator

It is less error-prone than NFD / replace accents / lowercase.

You can of course create the collator and reuse it:

```
var col = new Intl.Collator("cz", {sensitivity:"base"});
var result = col.compare("Čovjek", "covjek")
```

---

**Details**

Some problems with the NFD approach:
1. the differences can consistent of more than accents
2. the regexp does not cover all accents
3. lowercase conversion should be locale sensitive, not using the generic one
4. uppercase would be better than uppercase

**1. There is more than accents (example)**

In Japanese there are "narrow" and "wide" forms for Kana, so "ｽ" == "ス"
But

```
"ｽ".normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "").toLowerCase(); => "ｽ"
"ス".normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "").toLowerCase(); => "ス"
```

Not equal

But using Collator

```
Intl.Collator("jp", {sensitivity:"base"}).compare("ｽ", "ス") => 0 (equal, correct)
```

**2. The regexp does not cover all accents (example)**

Or Hebrew vowels (Niqqud) (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niqqud)

```
"כְּתִיב מָלֵא".normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "").toLowerCase(); => "כְּתִיב מָלֵא"
"כתיב מלא".normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "").toLowerCase(); => "כתיב מלא"
```

Not equal

But using Collator

```
Intl.Collator("he", {sensitivity:"base"}).compare("כתיב מלא", "כְּתִיב מָלֵא")
```

The result is 0 (equal, correct)

Similar for Arabic (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_diacritics)

**3. Locale sensitivity example**

Take the "well known Turkish I problem" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I)

```
"ı".normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "").toLowerCase(); => "ı"
"I".normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "").toLowerCase(); => "i"
```

So the result would be "not equal"

Using the collator, with bad a non-Turkish locale:

```
Intl.Collator("fr", {sensitivity:"base"}).compare("ı", "I") => 1 // not equal
```

Using the (correct) Turkish locale:

```
Intl.Collator("tr", {sensitivity:"base"}).compare("ı", "I") => 0 // equal
```

So the locale matters

**4. "Why uppercase" example**

In German "ß" uppercases to "SS" so "ß" == "SS" ignoring case
But

```
str1 = "ß".normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "").toLowerCase(); => "ß"
str2 = "SS".normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "").toLowerCase(); => "SS"
```

So the result would be "not equal"

But

```
Intl.Collator("de", {sensitivity:"base"}).compare("SS", "ß") => 0 (equal, correct)
```

**Note:** These are just some examples. Even if you say *"I don't care about Japanese / Hebrew / Turkish"* the proposed answer (with NFD) will fail in other locales. It is just not a good approach. Collator was designed to compare strings in an i18n aware way.

Comment: I totally agree that your solution should be used if you know the locale. Unfortunately in my case I don't know the locale and in fact it can be mixed - not within a single string, but within the strings that I want to search.
Fortunately the strings are limited to only a few different locales and for these cases the solution of @Morphyish works well enough. I'll integrate the ß/SS case though.

Comment: The lack of locale info only affects item 3, the others are still handled better with the Collator. • Even if you don't know the locale, you can use the default locale, or even "en", and you will get better results than NFC + lowercase. For default locale use Intl.Collator([], {sensitivity:"base"}). • The  ß/SS is just an example, you should not "solve" it by treating it as a special case. I can give you examples from Greek, if you want :-) • If you really-really want  to go the NFD way (why?), at least use uppercase.

Comment: I'm trying to make Intl.Collator work, but always get an empty result:
  
```  
const myStrings = ["Čovjek", "hello"];  
const searchText = "co";  
const collator = Intl.Collator(undefined, { sensitivity: "base", usage: "search" });   const filteredStrings = myStrings.filter((s) => { return collator.compare(s, this.searchText) === 0; });  
```  
  
I guess I'm misunderstanding `usage: "search"`. This option does not seem to enable partial matches.